# Pandas replace using dictionary and regular expression

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the following regular expression:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{2}\-\d{2})(?!\d)
```

with specific value.

For example

```
column = pd.Series(['01-01', '01-01 qwerasdf 0101-0101'])
```

I want to replace all `'01-01'` with `'0101'`

(but no digits before and after `'01-01'` so `'0101-0101'` will remain unchanged)

I can use the following to get what I want.

```
column = column.str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(\d{2}\-\d{2})(?!\d)', '0101', regex=True)
```

But now I have a dictionary to replace with

```
{'01-01': '0101', '01-02': '0102'...}
```

How can I use regular expression and dictionary at the same time in the replace function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use callback with dictionary, if no match return same value like for `05-07` with `dict.get`:

```
column = pd.Series(['01-01', '01-01 qwerasdf 0101-0101', '01-02 aa', '05-07 dd'])

d = {'01-01': '0101', '01-02': '0102'}
column = column.str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(\d{2}\-\d{2})(?!\d)', 
                            lambda x: d.get(x.group(), x.group()), 
                            regex=True)


print (column)
0                       0101
1    0101 qwerasdf 0101-0101
2                    0102 aa
3                   05-07 dd
dtype: object
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what x.group() means? Is it from the re module?

Comment: @k07224115 - yes, it is for match group.